# admob run on test device but when i run on real time it shows failed to load native add:0 , my app id created 3-4 days ago

Tags: android

```
private static final String ADMOB_AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-6965669387020729/3235162894";
private static final String ADMOB_APP_ID = "ca-app-pub-6965669387020729~1758429698"

adLoader.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do following steps and check

1. Check if Admob Id is correct or not.
2. You can add a adListner() to check if any error code and check it.
3. If you get any error , you can search it on google.
4. If not you can create a new id with different package name and use it as some time unwanted clicks can cause problems(refer admob docs).

All the best.

Comment: no bro its not working  i try with another person id and unit id then its work

Comment: have you implemented adListner to check the error code. if any error , will show in that.

Comment: try

adView.setAdListner(new AdListner())

somthing like that.

Comment: i have not found that method but it shows error code 0

Comment: private static final String ADMOB_AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110";
  private static final String ADMOB_APP_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"

Comment: Error code means that you Admob key is no longer working(Suspended)
So rename your application Package name and create new Admob id with new Package name(same as application).

Comment: when i try with above its work not work with my  info

Comment: have you tried googling what error 0 means in admob ?

Your Appid was deleted or blocked by admob.